# Python, Flask: Executemany with multiple fields in HTML form

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I don't know how can I improve this code, I'm trying to insert multiple data with same field with different values. Can someone improve my code?

```
<form action="/submits/ method="POST">

    <input type="text" name="book" value="Divergent">
    <input type="text" name="author" value="Veronica Roth">

    <input type="text" name="book" value="Allegiant">
    <input type="text" name="author" value="Veronica Roth">

    <input type="text" name="book" value="Inferno">
    <input type="text" name="author" value="Dan Brown">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

---

```
@app.route('/submits/', methods = ['POST'])
def books():
    if method == "POST":
        BOOK = request.form['book']
        AUTHOR = request.form['author']
        stmt = "INSERT INTO shelf (book_column, author_column) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        c.executemany(stmt, (BOOK, AUTHOR))
        conn.commit()
```

Comment: First of all remove the typo here `BOOK = request.form['book]` you need one more single quote after book.

Comment: 0decimal0 I'm not really sure if my code will really work, is it? I'm new to Python and Flask, may you consider this problem.

Comment: are you having errors executing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try use `getlist`:

```
if method == "POST":
    stmt = "INSERT INTO shelf (book_column, author_column) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    books = request.form.getlist('book')
    authors = request.form.getlist('author')
    for i, book in enumerate(books):
        c.executemany(stmt, (book, authors[i]))
        c.commit()
```